# passing data from select menu to another select menu AJAX Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I having a hard time doing this,I am using codeigniter php framework, basically I have 3 select menu and its value is from database like :

```
<?php

$this->data[selOne] = $this->model->selectOne();      //the id of this one must send
$this->data[selTwo] = $this->model->selectTwo();     //<-to here and the id of 2nd select 
$this->data[selThree] = $this->model->selectThree(); //must send to here <-

$this->load->view->('controller/index.php', $this->data);
?>
```

in my view

```
 <select>
    <?php foreach($selOne as $one){?>
    <option><?php echo $one->label;?></option>
    <?php }?>
 </select>

 <select>
    <?php foreach($selTwo as $one){?>
    <option><?php echo $one->label;?></option>
    <?php }?>
 </select>

 <select>
    <?php foreach($selThree as $one){?>
    <option><?php echo $one->label;?></option>
    <?php }?>
 </select>
```

I would like to achieve is

* when I select the first select menu It passes its value to the 2nd menu without refreshing the page.

* same as 2nd select menu it passes its value to the third select menu.

eg

in 1st select menu I select "Asia"

the 2nd select menu gets the value Asia so it show the country in Asia, also I click one of its country

the 3rd select it return the city in the country selected in 2nd select menu

no problem in sql part I just needed to know how to pass its value without refreshing the page.

could anyone help me achieve this, and please spare me.

Comment: did you know about jQuery.Ajax CI Ajax http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/216298/

Comment: @RameezSOOMRO yeah but very little.

Comment: i wrote a answer but before do it you must read jquery ajax and using ajax in CodeIgniter...

Answer (score 3):

//add class on first contents_name  in html

//your custom_jqueryfile.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").delegate('.contents_name','change',function () {
        var continent_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax( {
            type:GET,
            data: ({"continent_id":continent_id}),
            url: 'mysite.com/myajax',
            success: function (data_response) {
                $(".countries_target").html(data_response);
            },
            error:function () {
                alert('something went wrong!');
            }
        })
    } )
})
```

//CREATE NEW CI CONTOLLER 
///[learn about CI-URI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

```
class myajax extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__contruct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $check_uri_params = $this->uri->rsegment_array();
        //check where content_id showing print_r($check_uri_params) below URI_SEGMENTS to check in which params $content_id     

        ///$content_id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0); ---SOMETHING LIKE LEFT CODE TO GET CONTENT_ID
        $data['country_names'] = $this->db->get_where('country_name_table', array('id' => $content_id));
        $this->load->view('ajax_options',$data);            
    }
}
```

//Create views named it  ajax_options.php

```
echo '<select name="country_name">';
foreach($country_names as $country_name) {
        echo '<option value="'.$country_name['countryID_col_name'].'">'.$country_name['countryName_col_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

do it like this
    controller:

```
function get_zone_menu()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $zones  = $this->Location_model->get_zones_menu($id);

    foreach($zones as $id=>$z):?>

    <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $z;?></option>

    <?php endforeach;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('#f_country_id').change(function(){
        $.post('<?php echo site_url('locations/get_zone_menu');?>',{id:$('#f_country_id').val()}, function(data) {
          $('#f_zone_id').html(data);
        });
    });
```

});